# Custom frame shape for map layout

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.5, layouts

I was wondering if it is possible to get ArcMap 10.5 layouts to have frames similar to the one in this image (produced in Matlab),

[image: matlab default map europe]

rather than the default square/rectangle that my data is currently being framed in?

[image: my map]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ArcMap you can by [using the properties of the data frame to clip to a polygon feature](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/clipping-the-data-frame.htm).

The equivalent functionality, to clip to a map frame using a polygon feature, is not yet available in ArcGIS Pro.  However, you can Reshape a map frame to a polygon graphic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. The only issue with this is that you can't then define a background colour of the frame as it will extend to the square/rectangular extent of your frame. This can be pretty easily solved though.